# right align video element inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to right bottom align a video element inside a div. Following is the code I have so faar achieved aligning the video element to the bottom but unable to get it to the right side if the dive container:

```css
video {
}

.border.rounded-0.border-secondary.shadow-sm.d-md-flex.align-self-end.justify-content-md-end.align-items-md-end {
}

.border.rounded-0.border-secondary.shadow-sm.d-md-flex.align-self-end.justify-content-md-end.align-items-md-end {
}
```

```html
<div class="d-inline-flex" style="background-color: #141414;height: 400px;width: 100%;"><video class="border rounded-0 border-secondary shadow-sm d-md-flex align-self-end justify-content-md-end align-items-md-end" width="200" height="100" controls="" style="background-color: #e6e4e4;" preload="none" autoplay="" loop=""></video></div>
```

Please advise should i place it inside a span?

Comment: add you code in code snippets, so that it is more convient to solve problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: You also have 2 class declarations in that `<div>`. Put the first `d-inline-flex` in with your other classes, and see how that goes first. It will ignore the 2nd if you have the first, so that's probably your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you just add  `flex-direction: row-reverse` to your d-inline-flex class, you should get the result you want.

As the css you posted was empty and duplicated, I removed these classes from the snippet. I also put your inline-style from the video into a video css class, just to neaten the code.

Hope this helps

p.s just noticed the 'bottom' part of your question. align-items using flex-end will position the video at the bottom (I thought you wanted it at the top)..

//at right bottom

```css
.d-inline-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
  background-color: #141414;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

video {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #e6e4e4;
  justify-content:center;
  align-self:flex-end;
  align-content:flex-end;

}
```

```html
<div class="d-inline-flex" style="background-color: #141414;height: 400px;width: 100%;"><video class="border rounded-0 border-secondary shadow-sm d-md-flex" controls="" preload="none" autoplay="" loop=""></video></div>
```

//at right top

```css
.d-inline-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  background-color: #141414;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

video {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #e6e4e4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-inline-flex" style="background-color: #141414;height: 400px;width: 100%;"><video class="border rounded-0 border-secondary shadow-sm d-md-flex" controls="" preload="none" autoplay="" loop=""></video></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
video {
}

.border.rounded-0.border-secondary.shadow-sm.d-md-flex.align-self-end.justify-content-md-end.align-items-md-end {
}

.border.rounded-0.border-secondary.shadow-sm.d-md-flex.align-self-end.justify-content-md-end.align-items-md-end {
}
.d-inline-flex{
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-inline-flex" style="background-color: #141414;height: 400px;width: 100%;"><video class="border rounded-0 border-secondary shadow-sm d-md-flex align-self-end justify-content-md-end align-items-md-end" width="200" height="100" controls="" style="background-color: #e6e4e4;" preload="none" autoplay="" loop=""></video></div>
```